# How we can Create a Zip Folder of Publish Code in S3 Bucket

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

AWS Codebuild keeps throwing error - AWS Codebuild keeps throwing error - Command did not exit successfully cd ../OutPutDirecotry exit status 2

I'm trying to create a zip folder in S3 bucket after Publishing code.

Here is my buildspec:

```
build:
    commands:
       - echo Build started on `date`
       - dotnet build BillingData/BillingData.sln
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Publish started on `date`      
      - dotnet publish BillingData/BillingData.sln -c Release -r linux-x64 -p:PublishDir=.\publish -o BillingArtifacts
      - cd ../BillingArtifacts
      - zip -r myBuild.zip
```

How can I create a Zip folder after run dotnet publish.

I don't have a clue what is wrong here.

Comment: Codebuild have capability to zip your  artifacts. It can be done by enabling output artifacts format to zip

Comment: Thanks @AkshayGopani, Yes after investigation I have resolved that exception through Output artifacts.